# Is it possible to use a btCompoundShape as a child shape of a different btCompoundShape?

Tags: bullet, bulletphysics

The question is fairly self explanatory. I am left with the need for a single `btRigidBody` made up of an incredibly large number of `btBoxShape` primitives. The way my program is written currently lends itself rather well to the setup I described in the question where there are multiple `btCompoundShape` objects that contain these `btBoxShape` primitives, and all of them can feed into one over arching `btCompoundShape` which is the shape that would then by used by the `btRigidBody`.

Unfortunately, it will take some time to implement, and I am hoping to have a yes or no answer before I begin so that I can go about other means if necessary. That being said, if no answer is forthcoming I will go ahead anyway and answer my own question here after attempting the implementation myself.

Comment: In the end I decided not to even try the implementation as the more that I thought about it, the less likely to be possible it seemed. I reached this conclusion because the very definition of the `btCompoundShape` is that it is a concave shape made of several convex one. If it is a concave shape, it cannot be be a convex one in another `btCompoundShape`. This is of course just my theory, so if anyone does attempt the implementation themselves and finds me to be incorrect, please to say so here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a btCompoundShape child shape to a btCompoundShape: it allows recursion.

Comment: Really? Is this a practise best avoided or is it completely safe to do so?

Comment: I've just implemented things this way and it has sped execution up whilst reducing both the amount of code and the complexity of said code.